# Question concerning the GAP package qpa (find all ideals with a certain property)

Tags: abstract-algebra, computer-science, gap

I have the following question concerning the GAP package qpa.

> Let $k$ be a fixed finite field and let $Q$ be a fixed quiver. Let $kQ$ denote
>   the associated path algebra.
>
> Since $k$ is finite, there are only finitely many admissible ideals $I$ of $kQ$ with the property $I^u=0$ for some fixed natural number $u$.
>
> I would like to know, if there is a way to tell qpa to find all such
>   ideals, and, if so, how to do this.
>
> With other words, my input is: $[k,Q,u]$ and the output should be a list
>   containing all quiver algebras $kQ/I$ as entries (with all ideals I fulfilling the above criteria).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried to ask QPA authors (see them at  http://www.math.ntnu.no/~oyvinso/QPA/)? QPA is not even redistributed (perhaps yet) with GAP, so perhaps contacting the authors directly is the best way to get some support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[The answer is now posted at the GAP Forum [here](http://mail.gap-system.org/pipermail/forum/2014/004609.html), so I am just reproducing it here as a Community Wiki answer to remove this question from the unanswered queue]*

```
Dear Bernhard and the GAP Forum,

I am a little bit confused concerning "... admissible ideals  I  of
kQ  with the property  I^u=0 for some fixed natural number  u".
Are you restricting to quivers without oriented cycles? Or are you
thinking of quotients  A=kQ/I, where  I  is an admissible ideal such
that the radical of A, rad A, satisfies  (rad A)^u = 0?  I assume that
you are considering the latter case.

Let J be the ideal generated by the arrows in the path algebra kQ.
Consider the ring R = kQ/J^u.  This is a finite dimensional algebra.
You are asking for all twosided ideals of R which is contained in
J^2/J^u, or equivalently, all sub-bimodules of J^2/J^u, that is, all
submodules of J^2/J^u as a module over the enveloping algebra R^e of R
(that is, R\otimes_k R^\op, which can be constructed in QPA).  So
actually you are asking: given a module M over a finite dimensional
quotient (in your case R^e) of a path algebra, find all the submodules
of M.

This, I think, can very soon become a CPU and a memory intensive
undertaking, given the "correct" examples.  However, in this situation
one knows the simple modules, so one could inductively build all
submodules from either constructing all maximal submodules of  M
or all simple submodules of  M, where the situation which creates
"problems" would be when the top or the socle of  M  is not a basic
module.  It should however be possible to write such an algorithm
within QPA, but I don't know anybody having done it yet.

So, to my knowledge there is no way to find all such ideals.

I hope that these comments are helpful.

Best wishes, Oeyvind Solberg.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Do you know, how I can write a reply in the GAP Forum in that thread (I never did it before)?

Comment: @BernhardBoehmler: to post to the Forum, you should subscribe to it first - see "Subscribing and posting to the Forum" at [this page](http://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/Forum/forum.html).

Comment: @BernhardBoehmler: ah, perhaps I misunderstood your question, since it seems that you're already subscribed. Then just reply to the Øyvind Solberg's email from your mail application, using the same email address that is used for the Forum subscription.